Create new PS5 partition on HDD containing PS4 games
I have an external HDD mounted on a PS5 in which I have stored games for PS4 (my previous console).
Only now I realized that I can't save new PS5 games on the HDD (but only PS4 games).
I'm wondering if I can add a new partition to the HDD and format it to save PS5 games but I'm afraid of losing current data.
Any hint is appreciated.

Not a full answer, but an alternative is to install a second M2 drive into the ps5. The ps5 makes this really easy to do

If you want to format the HDD to create a new partition you will definitely lose your current data.
I found this on Reddit, (which is not completely on topic but it fits your case imho):

I just did this. It shows the exFAT partition but makes you format the drive, then recombines the partitions and formats them as one. I lost my stuff that was on the other partition. It wasn't a lot or anything too important that I care about. But yeah, it doesn't look like it supports partitions.

By the way, there aren't many advantages in storing PS5 games on an external storage, because you can't play them from it. You always have to copy the game on the internal storage in order to start it.

Unfortunately, you were right: it's no possible to play PS5 games from external HDD
https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/hardware/ps5-extended-storage/#:~:text=Not%20all%20devices%20are%20guaranteed,only%20one%20at%20a%20time. Now I'm trying to connect another HDD (even if I know only one at time an work) to use it for PS5 games I don't need to play but to store. I'll post my achivements.
